# Комментарии для сайта

Tags: php, комментарии

Всем привет. Внизу вы видите комментарии, мне нужно реализовать такую же систему. Вот поля какие мне кажется необходимы. Объясню некоторые поля: **id_user** - автор, **comment_id** - id главного комментария, если 0, то считается главным.

[image]

[image]

Насколько правильная логика? прошу помощи, рассмотрю  любое предложение

Comment: Почему не id_comment? :)
А так, вроде нормальная логика. По крайней мере, понятная.

Comment: аа, против системы))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а для чего **id_post**? это вообще что? и к чему.

или **id_post** это изначально значение null т.е. главный комментарий, а если он дочерний то он принимает значение id главного комментария? Тогда зачем **comment_id**

Распиши логику того как должно работать.

как они соединяются у тебя через что?

//upd
Гы, да что-то я сглупил. ведь это комментарии :)

id // порядковый номер
id_user // лузер
id_post  // пост
parent // родительский комментарий 
date  // дата
text  // текст

Но при таком варианте, у нас к статье может быть 20-100 комментариев-родителей, к которым написаны комментарии. Понятно объясняю? Коммент к комменту!

Тогда как ты будешь сортировать их и учитывать кто из них к какому комментарию комментарий?

Пример комментариев:

1. Первый коммент // id 1
2. Элемент списка  // id 2
3. Элемент списка   // id 5
4. Второй коммент // id 9
5. Второй коммент  // id 3
6. Элемент списка  // id 4
7. Элемент списка // id 6
8. Второй коммент  // id 7
9. Третий коммент  // id 8

> ```
>    id    |   id_user |  id_post  |    parent  |  date     | text
>     1    |     1     |    123    |      0      |12/02/2013 | текст 
>     2     |     3     |    123    |      1      |12/02/2013 | текст 
>     3     |     1     |    123    |      0      |12/02/2013 | текст 
>     4     |     4     |    123    |      3      |12/02/2013 | текст 
>     5     |     4     |    123    |      1      |12/02/2013 | текст 
>     6     |     2     |    123    |      3      |12/02/2013 | текст 
>     7     |     10    |    123    |      3      |12/02/2013 | текст 
>     8     |     1     |    123    |      3      |12/02/2013 | текст 
>     9     |     1     |    123    |      1      |12/02/2013 | текст
> ```

Можно сначала получить главные комментарии, потом получить комменты к комментам и отсортировать их по дате, но не много ли это времени и сил займет?

Мне просто понять почему именно рассматривается один уровень вложенности?
Можно сделать и 2 и 3 и 10 как на хабре. структура таблицы изменится немного.

Comment: это id поста в блоге, комментарии будут выводиться для определённого поста, (как комментарии в блоге)

Comment: ну это рекурсия, заморочек больше, представляю как это сделать, но это мне кажется геморно))

Answer (score 3):

Идея хорошая, только названия полей я бы взял немного другие.

```
  comment_id  "ИД комментария
  parent_id   "ИД главного (родительского) комментария
  user_id     "от кого
  date        "дата
  text        "текст
```

Answer (score 0):

Что не так? выводятся только родительские комментарии

```
    /*
     @comment_id - id комментария
     @parent_id  - id родительского комментария
     @post_id    - id поста таблице posts
     @user_id    - id пользователя оставившего комментарий
     @text       - текст комментария
     @date       - время добавления комментария
    */
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment") or die ('Error #626732');
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql)){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            if (!$row['parent_id']){
                echo '<b>'.$row['text'].'</b><br><br><br>';
            }else{
                    if ($row['parent_id'] == $row['comment_id']){
                        echo $row['text'];
                    }
                }
            }
    } else {
        echo 'добавить коммент';
    }
```

Comment: А с какой стати должно выполняться условие ``($row['parent_id'] == $row['comment_id'])``?  
Место для вопроса вы выбрали оригинальное

Comment: ну если имя родителя равно текущему id комментария которого выводится, показываем комментарий

Comment: Не правильно, не "имя родителя равно текущему id комментария", а "id родителя текущего комментария равно текущему id комментария", что само по себе не логично.