# Не показываются ответ комментария родителя

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

При ответ на комментарий выводится всё как надо, но если создать ещё комментарии и ответить на первый, то он показывает его во втором. Как быть.

```
<?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE post = '$id'") or die ('Error #626732');
        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                if (!$row['parent_id']){
                    echo '
                    <div class="com">
                        <p>
                            <img src="'.$row['avatar'].'" alt="Аватарка">
                            <span id="name">Комментарий добавил(а): <strong>'.$row['user'].'</strong></span><br>
                            <span id="data">Дата: <strong>'.$row['date'].'</strong></span>
                        </p><br><br>
                        <p>'.$row['text'].'</p>
                        <p>'.$row['comment_id'].' comment_id</p><br>
                        <p>'.$row['id'].' id</p>
                        <button id="otv" value="'.$row['id'].'" onclick="otv(this)">Ответить</button>

                        <form class="form_otvet form_otv'.$row['id'].'" action="comment_otv.php" method="post">
                        <p>
                          <label>
                            Ваше имя<br>
                            <input type="text" name="name" size="30">
                          </label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label>
                            Ваш Email<br>
                            <input type="email" name="email" size="30">
                          </label>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          <label>
                            Комментарий<br>
                            <textarea name="message" cols="33" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
                          </label>
                        </p><br><br>
                        <p>
                          <input type="hidden" name="id_post" value="'.$id.'">
                          <input type="hidden" name="id_com" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                          <input type="submit" id="submit_com" name="submit_com" value="Ответить">
                        </p>
                      </form>
                      </div>
                    ';
                }else{
                    if ($row['parent_id'] == $row['comment_id']){
                        echo '
                        <div class="com otv">
                            <p>
                                <img src="'.$row['avatar'].'" alt="Аватарка">
                                <span id="name">Ответил(а): <strong>'.$row['user'].'</strong></span><br>
                                <span id="data">Дата: <strong>'.$row['date'].'</strong></span>
                            </p><br><br>
                            <p>'.$row['text'].'</p>
                            <p>'.$row['comment_id'].'</p>
                            <button id="otv" value="'.$row['id'].'" onclick="otv(this)">Ответить</button>

                            <form class="form_otvet form_otv'.$row['id'].'" action="comment_otv.php" method="post">
                                <p>
                                <label>
                                    Ваше имя<br>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" size="30">
                                </label>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <label>
                                    Ваш Email<br>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" size="30">
                                </label>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <label>
                                    Комментарий<br>
                                    <textarea name="message" cols="33" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
                                </label>
                                </p><br><br>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id_post" value="'.$id.'">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id_com" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                                    <input type="submit" id="submit_com" name="submit_com" value="Ответить">
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    ';
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo 'добавить коммент';
        }
        ?>
```

Вот таблица

[image: Таблица]

Вот что получается 
[image: Комментарий]

скрипт взял от сюда [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/196807/Комментарии-для-сайта/196904#196904?newreg=cbfa42e2499a459a9f046abc0c90a962](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/196807/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/196904#196904?newreg=cbfa42e2499a459a9f046abc0c90a962)

Comment: Для начала не мешать верстку с кодом. Точнее мешать можно, но не как у вас

Comment: А как мне еще её вставить. Мне так удобнее

Comment: Через `echo` выводить? Прекратите читать статьи 90-2000-х годов)

Comment: можно конечно printf выводить

Comment: Но вопрос заключается не в правильности вывода, а почему не срабатывает условие

Comment: Вот вы показали скриншот, поясните что такое `comment_id` и `parent_id`. Как по вашей таблице определить что строка с `id=5` относится именно к `id=1`?

Comment: comment_id - это id родителя parent_id - это ответ на комментарий

Comment: Ну дык у вас 5-й комментарий относится ко 2-му, проверяйте передачу/сохранение данных

Comment: Всё равно не получается. Может что-то в условии не так я всё перепробовал

Comment: mysql отдает строки в том порядке как ему захочется. ваш текущий код как минимум ожидает, что бы потомок пришел из БД после родителя. Был бы у вас не MySQL то можно было бы воспользоваться рекурсивными запросами. Вам же  остается только собрать сначала все данные в памяти в правильной иерархии и только потом их выводить.

Comment: Сначала читаем все записи в массив с ключами по их id. Потом делаем по этому массиву цикл, для каждой записи у которой нет парента вызывающей функцию, которая перекладывает детей прямо в этот узел. при этом перед тем как переложить очередной элемент рекурсивно вызывает себя, что бы найти и переложить детей текущего элемента в него. В принципе можно аккуратно совместить это с выводом. Данные из БД стоит выбирать уже отсортированными по дате, что бы по крайней мере уже порядок в элементах был и более поздний не вывелся раньше предыдущего

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю, что вопрос не про форматирование кода (и я схлопочу минусы), но попробуйте писать хотя бы так (в отсутствие шаблонизаторов):

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE post = '{$id}'") or die ('Error #626732');
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        if (!$row['parent_id']){
            $nameText="Комментарий добавил(а):";
            $addClass="";
        }else{
            if ($row['parent_id'] == $row['comment_id']){
                $nameText="Ответил(а):";
                $addClass=" otv";
            }
        }
?>
<div class="com<?=$addClass?>">
    <p>
        <img src="<?=$row['avatar']?>" alt="Аватарка"> <!--забудьте про параметр alt, оставляйте его всегда пустым-->
        <span id="name"><?=$nameText?><strong><?=$row['user']?></strong></span><br>
        <span id="data">Дата: <strong><?=$row['date']?></strong></span>
    </p><br><br>
    <p><?=$row['text']?></p>
    <p><?=$row['comment_id']?></p>
    <button id="otv" value="<?=$row['id']?>" onclick="otv(this)">Ответить</button>
</div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
<form class="form_otvet form_otv<?=$row['id']?>" action="comment_otv.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>
            Ваше имя<br>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="30">
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Ваш Email<br>
            <input type="email" name="email" size="30">
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Комментарий<br>
            <textarea name="message" cols="33" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
        </label>
    </p><br><br>
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_post" value="<?=$id?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_com" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
        <input type="submit" id="submit_com" name="submit_com" value="Ответить">
    </p>
</form>
```

Это позволит абстрагироваться от простыни кода и сконцентрироваться на задаче.

А по вашему вопросу: покажите хотя бы скриншоты таблиц с данными (обновив вопрос свой), дабы понять откуда растут ноги. В частности, что за поле `parent_id`?

Comment: parent_id - это id ответа